# Behind the scenes explanation of react controlled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the code for a controlled component from React's documentation.

```
class CustomInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render called');
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} />
    );
  }
}
```

This renders a `<input>` field which I cannot edit. I am just curious of how this is wired internally by react. Who's blocking my `keypress` events? Does react hook up a `keypress` event handler with `e.preventDefault()` to ensure I cannot type anything?

Codepen URL: https://codepen.io/mudassir0909/pen/MvQwGm?editors=0010

Comment: Are you certain that `input` field is non-editable?

Comment: @Umesh https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010, comment out the line inside `handleChange`

Answer (score 1):

So, I did some digging into React codebase. React wraps all the native events using something called [`Syntehtic Events`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). The interesting difference here is that in native HTML when you register an event using

```
myInput.addEventListener("click", (event) => /** do something */);
```

The event is registered on that particular element, that is the value of `event.currentTarget` in the above example is always `myInput`. More about [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

In case of React, let's consider the following component

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" click="handleClick" value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }
}
```

Inside the `handleClick` event listener, if you get the native event's `currentTarget` using `event.nativeEvent.currentTarget` you will always get `document` as value.

Basically, React listens to all the types of events that your browser supports at the `document` level & delegates them on the appropriate [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) aka [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation).

Whenever you're doing `onClick/onBlur/onSubmit` inside your JSX elements, (in simple words) React is keeping a map of the `JSX.Element` & the listener.

Whenever any event is triggered on the `document`, React checks if the `nativeEvent.target` has an event registered on the above event map. If there is one, it invokes that listener.

In case of a `controlled` example: unless you register an `onChange` event to modify the `state.value`, the component re-render will never happen i.e. the `<input />` just stays in it's previous form & looks like it is un-editable.

That is, whenever an `input` & other form elements are provided a `value` attribute in JSX, React treats them differently than the ones which do not have `value` property specified([`uncontrolled components`](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)). Also, the reason why React starts screaming if you provide a `value` attribute but do not implement `onChange`.